# Click on webpage button function doesnt work in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a fedex tracking automation but I'm unable to get the Track button clicked. any idea please?

```
Sub Fedex()
    
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html"
    
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE = 4
    Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
    
    Set searchbx = IE.document.getElementsByName("trackingnumber")(0)
    searchbx.Value = "Howdy!"

    IE.document.getElementById("btnSingleTrack").Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit - Do it direct via url parameter

You can manipulate the url you navigate. Look at the following example. Change the value of the last parameter `YourTrackingNumberHere` to a working tracking number and test it manually:

`https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&cntry_code=us&locale=en_US&trackingnumber=YourTrackingNumberHere`

### First answer to make it work in your way

The search box has events. You must trigger the change event after setting your tracking number. I never seen it before, but after triggering the change event, you must wait a few seconds to make the button click work.

```
Sub Fedex()
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim searchBox As Object
  
  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate "https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html"
  Do While ie.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  Set searchBox = ie.document.getElementsByName("trackingnumber")(0)
  searchBox.Value = "Howdy!"
  'Trigger the change event of the input box
  Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, searchBox, "change")
  'I don't know why, but you have to wait a few seconds
  'Otherwise the button click will not work
  'In my tests, I need 5 seconds to make it work in every case
  'You can make your own tests for your environment
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
  
  ie.document.getElementById("btnSingleTrack").Click
End Sub
```

With this procedure you can trigger every event:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked!  thanks so much @Zwenn! could I have one more ask/question? if I try to read out the actual value like this I get a 438 error.  'strAdd = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("redesignSnapshotTVC.snapshotController_date.dest").innerText
  
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = strAdd'

Comment: @Petolicious You have forgotten at least the index in the round brackets behind `getElementsByClassName()(hereTheIndex)`. Does your code wait until the page is fully loaded before you access it?

Comment: @Zween this is how the box, where the value is that I need, look like <h1 class="redesignSnapshotTVC tank-heading-primary tank-text-center tank-heading-margin-l" tabindex="0"><div class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_addr_label dest" title="Scheduled delivery: ">Scheduled delivery: </div><div class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_date dest">Wednesday  11/18/2020 by  4:30 pm</div><div class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_est dest" style="display: none;">

Comment: <div class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_est_time_label dest"></div></div><div class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_est_time dest" style="display: none;"><span class="edt_start_time"></span> <span class="edt_end_time"></span></div></h1>

Comment: @Zween yes the code runs till that line of the code. webpage opens, tracking ID is entered and button pushed and the ETA date from Fedex is shown

Comment: @Petolicious There are three class names `redesignSnapshotTVC`, `snapshotController_date` and  `dest`. If you want to use all 3, you must not put a dot in between. The space remains. If it is the only element on the page with these 3 classes, the index to use is 0 with this line: `strAdd = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_date dest")(0).innerText`

Comment: @Zween you saved me! could I have one last question - promise. if you search on the webpage and it doesnt find a tracking number it practically states no results found but then the code fails as it can't read the data. would you know if a elegant way to handle the error? the code reades like this now and works like a charm (thanks to YOU) if the numbers are present

Comment: `Sub Fedex()
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim searchBox As Object
  
  Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate "https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html"
  Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  For intRow = 2 To 30
  
      Set searchBox = ie.document.getElementsByName("trackingnumber")(0)
      searchBox.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & intRow).Value
      
      Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, searchBox, "change")`

Comment: `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
      
      ie.document.getElementById("btnSingleTrack").Click
      
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
      
      strAdd = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_date dest")(0).innerText
      On Error
      
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & intRow).Value = strAdd
  Next
  
End Sub`

Comment: `Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub`

Comment: @Zween any thoughts? Sorry for chasing